# Anypoint Studio APIKit Router - The file api.raml does not exist

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I am trying to import my RAML file and generate the required flows in an existing project using the APIKit router.
The RAML I am importing is straight from the zip produced by the API Manager which says it is valid and also when opening it in Anypoint Studio there are no problems (it is valid).
Now for the problem - when I bring the APIKit router component into the project and add a configuration, I select the RAML file as normal but when I click add mappings I get the following error:

"The file api.raml does not exist. Please, specify an existing RAML file or leave the RAML file field empty. This last option is useful when a RAML file does not exist yet."

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hi @MikeCon94, did you try generating flow using the zip? If you have multiple raml then you need to generate flow using the zip. If only one then extract the file from zip and you can associate it from the APIKit router. What I normally do is let mule generate the flow for me and not doing it manually.

Comment: I did try to do that but that also failed as it said the RAML was invalid, but when I opened it up it was the !include statements and when I deleted and added a character from them they were then valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the RAML file was invalid but for some reason the API Manager and the Anypoint Studio editor did not highlight this. The issue was I had used the displayName parameter in a bad location (below a get:). Interesting that the APIKit Router wasn't able to ignore this whilst the other tools did though!

Answer (score 0):

@Ralph Rimorin is correct.Extract RAML file and use RAML file to generate flow.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the flows are generated automatically as soon as raml is integrated or any other code is written..but in case I would suggest you manually extract and use it to design the flow...if it's possible...even check your runtime etc...hope it works fine for you...